# Inserting and checking data via stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert new data into a table and at the same time check if any of the data(treatments) is conflicting with each other according to a 'conflict' attribute in one of the tables. I'm not quite sure if my PL/SQL is actually fully correct, but i am currently getting an error when i try to insert new data saying "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows". I cant quite figure out what this means exactly. My procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FPRESC (
    FP_ID VARCHAR2,
    FTREAT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FCLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FDOC_ID VARCHAR2,
    FP_DATE DATE)
AS
   V_CLIENT_ID PRESCRIPTION.CLIENT_ID%TYPE;
   V_CONFLICT TREATMENTS.CONFLICT%TYPE;
   V_P_DATE PRESCRIPTION.P_DATE%TYPE;
   V_TREAT_ID TREATMENTS.TREAT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT P.CLIENT_ID, T.CONFLICT, P.P_DATE, T.TREAT_ID
    INTO V_CLIENT_ID, V_CONFLICT, V_P_DATE, V_TREAT_ID
    FROM PRESCRIPTION P, TREATMENTS T
    WHERE P.TREAT_ID=T.TREAT_ID;

    IF FP_DATE = V_P_DATE AND FCLIENT_ID = V_CLIENT_ID AND FTREAT_ID = V_TREAT_ID AND V_CONFLICT != NULL THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONFLICT');
    ELSE
         INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (P_ID, TREAT_ID, CLIENT_ID, DOC_ID, P_DATE)
         VALUES (FP_ID, FTREAT_ID, FCLIENT_ID, FDOC_ID, FP_DATE);
    END IF;
END FPRESC;
/
```

and here is an example of the data i am inserting:

```
 EXEC FPRESC ('P00011', 'T016', 'C00017', 'D006', '28-NOV-14');
```

This example inserts conflicting data, so i can test if the procedure will be able to identify the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.CLIENT_ID, T.CONFLICT, P.P_DATE, T.TREAT_ID
    INTO V_CLIENT_ID, V_CONFLICT, V_P_DATE, V_TREAT_ID
    FROM PRESCRIPTION P, TREATMENTS T
    WHERE P.TREAT_ID=T.TREAT_ID;
```

This select should fetch only one record for the logic to work, because of the INTO clause.. You're getting the error because your select is fetching more than 1 row. Fix your logic and it should work..

Answer (score 0):

To follow on with @Shankar, what you have will return every row in the tables where a join exists. You need to filter the results down to a specific row. Probably something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FPRESC (
    FP_ID VARCHAR2,
    FTREAT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FCLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FDOC_ID VARCHAR2,
    FP_DATE DATE)
AS
   V_ROWCOUNT NUMBER;
   V_CLIENT_ID PRESCRIPTION.CLIENT_ID%TYPE;
   V_CONFLICT TREATMENTS.CONFLICT%TYPE;
   V_P_DATE PRESCRIPTION.P_DATE%TYPE;
   V_TREAT_ID TREATMENTS.TREAT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO V_ROWCOUNT
    FROM PRESCRIPTION P, TREATMENTS T
    WHERE P.TREAT_ID=T.TREAT_ID
          AND P.CLIENT_ID = FCLIENT_ID
          AND P.P_DATE = FP_DATE
          AND T.TREAT_ID = FTREAT_ID
          AND V_CONFLICT != NULL;

    IF (V_ROWCOUNT > 0) THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONFLICT');
    ELSE
         INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (P_ID, TREAT_ID, CLIENT_ID, DOC_ID, P_DATE)
         VALUES (FP_ID, FTREAT_ID, FCLIENT_ID, FDOC_ID, FP_DATE);
    END IF;
END FPRESC;
```

Comment: P_ID is a new value that is being inserted into a table so it does not exist yet, so with your example 'no data found' error will come up

Comment: Ah, I understand. So what you really need to do is check if there are any rows in the table where the criteria are already entered. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: it compiles but does not work as intended. You seem to have excluded V_CONFLICT which is required to determine which treatments conflict with each other. Still not sure how to implement this, CONFLICT is stored in treatments table, while most other attributes are from prescription table

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the V_CONFLICT. Essentially you need to know if there are any rows which match your IF statement. You can't run the IF statement after the select, you need to add it to the where condition if your select so that every row is evaluated, then it returns a 0 if no rows match (there's no conflict) or > 0 if any rows match (there is a conflict). I've updated to include V_CONFLICT.

Comment: CONFLICT is an attribute of Treatments table. When the new data is entered into a Prescription table i want to check the treatment id against the treatment id in the Treatments table to see if the conflicts match. Overall the idea is not to have the same patient booking 2 conflicting treatments on the same day